# \includegraphics seems to be case-insensitive under Linux

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

It seems that \includegraphics isn't paying attention to case in file names. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[justified,marginals=raggedright]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{Simpson}
\end{document}
```

I have two files in this directory, one named Simpson.jpeg (a picture of Thomas Simpson, of Simpson's Rule fame, not Homer Simpson) and another named simpson.pdf (a graph illustrating simpson's rule).  When I process the latex file above with pdflatex, I see the following in the log:

```
<Simpson.pdf, id=4, pagebox=cropbox, 361.35pt x 252.945pt>
File: Simpson.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use Simpson.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: Simpson.pdf  used on input line 5. on input line 5.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 361.34912pt x 252.94438pt on input lin
e 5.
```

There isn't any file named Simpson.pdf.  What gets inserted into the output file is the graph in simpson.pdf.

I know I can work around this by just giving Simpson.jpeg as the file name, but I'm puzzled that \includegraphics is case-insensitive, and I'm worried that I'll stumble over this again later on.

For what it's worth, this is under Linux, where I'd most expect case-sensitivity.  If this is expected behavior, is there any way I can turn it off?

**Update:**

Marcel Krüger provided a solution, below, but I just wanted to note a couple of things for the benefit of anybody else who runs into this.

First of all, I would have assumed that \includegraphics would look for exact matches for all of the possible extensions first, and then if none were found would look for case-insensitive matches.  I haven't done enough tests to be sure, but it looks like it's actually doing things in the opposite order: Looking for an exact match for each possible extension, then looking for case-insensitive matches for that extension, then moving on the the next extension and repeating.

Second, I think the way the file name is reported in the log is a bug.  The log should tell you the actual name of the file it found, not a fictitious name of a non-existent file.  It might be hard to get the real name, depending on how the case-insensitive search works, but it would be nice to fix this.

Comment: this is implemented in the core web2c file handling not specific to includegraphics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In TeX Live the library kpathsea is used to lookup files and since 2018 it falls back to case-insensitive lookups by default if a file with a given name isn't found case sensitively. You can disable this behavior by setting the environment variable `texmf_casefold_search` to `0` or by adding `texmf_casefold_search = 0` in your `texmf.cnf` configuration file.

Comment: To get this straight; if OP had used `\includegraphics{Simpson.jepg}` (i.e. with the ending) it would have included the right image?

Comment: @Lupino Yes. (As also mentioned in the question) (With `.jpeg` instead of `.jepg` of course)